# Converting a string to an array of json objects and then querying the json

Tags: sql, json

I have the following string:

```
'[{"start":"s1","end":"e1"},{"start":"s2","end":"e2"}]'
```

I want to be able to execute an SQL query that returns 2 columns as follows:

```
start   end
s1      e1
s2      e2
```

I'm envisioning something like

```
with t as (
    select '[{"start":"s1","end":"e1"},{"start":"s2","end":"e2"}]' as data
)
```

select ??? from t

Can someone fill in the ???

Comment: JSON functions are highly vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) you can use the `->>` operator together with `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
with t(data) as (
  values ('[{"start":"s1","end":"e1"},{"start":"s2","end":"e2"}]'::jsonb)
)
select a.item ->> 'start' as "start", 
       a.item ->> 'end' as "end"
from t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as a(item)
```